# Why is it necessary to override getData() in Recycler class on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Why do I need to override a generic method that returns a generic class like `ArrayList` when inheriting certain classes? Correct me if I'm wrong, but for a generic class such as ArrayList it seems like it would be redundant and unnecessary.

```
public class Data {
    public static ArrayList<Information> getData() {
        ArrayList<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] images = {R.drawable.img_1,R.drawable.img_2,R.drawable.img_3};
        String[] text = {"image_1", "image_2", "image_3"};

        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            Information current = new Information();
            current.imageId = images[i];
            current.title = text[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }
}

public class Information {
    public int imageId;
    public String title;
}
```

Comment: it is model POJO. it contains your data that you display in recycle view\

Comment: Edited to try to clear up the unclear wording. Also think the question might be unclear about the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Information` is POJO data and in `ArrayList<Information>` mean that list content should be like `Information POJO`.

for example in ArrayList stringsList, list's data should be `string` and you can add data to string with way :

```
  stringsList.add("firstString")
  stringsList.add("  ")
  stringsList.add(5+"")
  and....
```

but about `Information` type :

```
   ArrayList<Information> infoList=new ArrayList();

   for(int i = 0 ; i<10){

     Information info=new Information;
     info.imageId=i;
     info.title="title : "+i;

     infoList.add(info)

   }
```

that after above codes , you `infoList` , contain 10 `Information` object item.